# React Native "fetch" returning a network error

Tags: javascript, http, react-native, networking

I am creating an application using react native that works as currently existing website. i am using the "fetch" method to make Http POST requests to the server to return JSON Object. 
using this method:

```
HttpRequest = (RequestURL, callback) => {

    var AdminLoginBindingModel = {
      usr: this.state.username,
      pwd: this.state.password,
    }

    this.setState({Response: "Performing Fetch..."});

    fetch(RequestURL,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },     
      body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(obj => callback(obj))
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({displayMessage: "Could Not Connect To Server", Response: "" + error});
    })                        
}
```

The correct response of a JSON object was being returned. without changing any code only testing it on my home network, as opposed to public network at the university I attend, The request now takes five minutes loading then returns a "Network Request Failed" error.
Does anyone know the cause/solution to this problem?

EDIT:
Testing this application on a 3G mobile network has the same result, a five minute wait then "Network Request Failed" error.

Comment: We will need to know what is the value of RequestURL as well as what is the exact status code of the answer

Comment: I would try using Postman app to see if the endpoint is reachable.
On the other hand, I would try this code against a mocky.io url to see if it works correctly. But I suppose the issue is more on CORS permissions on the Url you are requesting

Comment: The request link is https://mibase-test.mibase.com.au/members/api/startSession.php it works in any browser by returning the JSON object. When trying the request with https://www.google.com the same error occurs

Comment: You are performing a GET when viewing on browsers, in your code, you re trying POST which may not work.

Comment: I understand that, but this exact code did work on a different network and when run on the actual website using a post request this request works

Comment: The issue is not on the code you provide but on the end point (and/or its network), we can't really help. Did you try with Postman? What is the status code?

Comment: the status code is 200, That should mean there is a stable connection. i'm not sure what the issue exactly was. i was hoping someone else had also had this error and found a solution for it